# Positioning of figures in sections and avoid blank pages with float package

Tags: pdf, latex

I have the problem that latex creates empty pages while using the float package.
This is the Code:

```
\section{Sample}
Sample Text.
\section{Title}

\begin {figure}[H]
Insert figure via R-Code.
\captionlistentry{Title Boxplot}
Insert figure via R-Code.
\captionlistentry{Dressiergrad Boxplot}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
Insert figure via R-Code.
\captionlistentry{Reckgrad Boxplot}
\end{figure}
```

So i got 2 Sections "Sample" and "Example ". In Sample there is some text and in Title there are 3 figures. 2 of the figures and the section heading are fitting onto 1 page.

So there should be smth. like that:

Page1: Sample title + text

Page2: Example title + 2 figures

Page3: 1 figure

But Latex makes this:

Page1: Sample title + text

Page2: Empty Page

Page3: Example title + 2 figures

Page4: 1 figure

I'm using documentclass{article}, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `[H]` option. If the image sizes are little bigger than what can be fit in the same page, LaTeX pushes it to the next page.

As a second option, you can reduce the size of the image a little bit!

Comment: this isn't really working well...Now the title (done with \subsection{}) will not appear on the same page like one image...and there is rly enough space.
Hmm making the Images smaller..could try that.
Anyway, tahnks for the answer so far!

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the pdf generated? may be I can articulate better what is happening!

Comment: I fixxed it, by positioning only 1 figure at one page, that doenst look so awesome, but its working, and right now, I don't got the time to change it.
Thanks for your help, maybe I will come back to this one Day :)